# GPU is not improving (cudamat)

Tags: python, numpy, gpgpu

The following code calculates the euclidean distance between X points of N dimensions and W fixed points (in the same space, N dimensions)

There are 10.000 X points, and only 14 W points.

Distance method calls are made in batches (of 2.000 points, and sometimes 200 or 20 points)

Distance operations involves matrixes multiplication of size (batchsizexN) x (Nx14).  Also involves element wise pow operations, and cols/rows sums.

Using the gpu has an overcost of copying both matrixes from the PC RAM to the NVidia RAM.  But I expected that in a space with high dimensionality (N = 1.000 dimensions) it were reverted into a time execution improvement.

But the attached code did a very bad results:

- with N=64 dimensions gpu was 0.2 times faster (cpu was 5 times faster than gpu)
- with N=1000 dimensions gpu and cpu has the same results
- with N=10000 dimensions gpu was 1.2 times faster than gpu
- with N=100000 dimensions gpu was 0.85 times faster than gpu

The CPU is Intel i7 and the gpu is Nvidia 750Ti.
I'm using an Ubuntu dedicated server.  I think that X windows is not using the graphic card.  I connect just vía vnc / ssh

The best improvement was of 1.2 versus just one thread of one i7 core.

I'm I newbie on GPUs.  Any help to have better results will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import cudamat as cm

def distance(self, X, useGPU=False):
    if useGPU:
        print("using GPU...")
        W=self.W
        gpu_W = cm.CUDAMatrix(W)
        gpu_X = cm.CUDAMatrix(X)
        gpu_D = cm.empty ((W.shape[0] , X.shape[0]) )
        gpu_X2 = cm.empty (X.shape)
        gpu_W2 = cm.empty (W.shape)

        cm.pow(gpu_X, 2, target=gpu_X2)
        gpu_X2 = gpu_X2.sum(axis=1)
        cm.pow(gpu_W, 2, target=gpu_W2)
        gpu_W2 = gpu_W2.sum(axis=1)

        gpu_D = cm.dot(gpu_W, gpu_X.T)
        gpu_D = gpu_D.mult((-2))
        gpu_D = gpu_D.add_col_vec(gpu_W2)
        gpu_D = gpu_D.add_row_vec(gpu_X2.transpose())

        D_T=gpu_D.transpose().asarray()

        return D_T
    else:
        W = self.W  
        X2 = (X**2).sum(1)[:, None]
        D = -2*np.dot(W, X.T) + (W**2).sum(1)[:, None] + X2.T
        return D.T
```

Comment: I know nothing about cudamat. however, I'll bet that you are paying an enormous overhead in fixed latency and wasted memory bandwidth launching what is effectively eight or nine separate kernels to perform such a trivial calculation. The solution probably to write a GPU kernel to do the operation and skip the cudamat elementwise primitives altogether